# How to place a text inside Rectangle BoxView in XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I'm using the list View in XAML, and using below codw to draw a rectangular box, I want to place a 2 letter alphabets inside the box like windows phone contacts they palce alphabets inside the rectangle box. Is there any way to place a text inside rectangle box

```
<BoxView Color="Green" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="Start">
```

Comment: use Label instead of a BoxView

Comment: Thanks Jason for your reply. Label is working fine, but is there any way that we can place a label text inside boxview

Comment: What do you need to do that a BoxView can do that a Label can't?  You can't place content inside a BoxView.  You could layer a Label on top of a BoxView, but it would be simpler to just use a Label by itself.

Answer (score 1):

You want to replicate what it looks like on WinPhone.

(Sorry no code, I don't have my computer with me)

1. Use a flattened *Frame* (HasShadows=false, CornerRadius=0)
2. Set the Padding=10, Margin=3 (breathing room),
   BackgroundColor=Green
3. Put a *Label* inside the *Frame*
4. Set FontSize=25, TextColor=White, Center it (Horizontal and
   Vertical Alignment), FontAttributes=Bold

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use like this 

<StackLayout Padding="1" BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

<StackLayout  BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
<Label Text="Sample" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"/>
</StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
May this will solve the problem.
```